# find filenames and replace a substring - in one line

Tags: bash, find

Trying to use `find` to change x->y in all files starting with a:

```
find . -iname "a*" -exec mv {} $(z="{}";echo ${z/x/y}) \;
```

but it's not working.

Would appreciate an explanation why.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have an order of operations error. `{}` is substituted by the `find` command at runtime, but expansions like your command substitution happen before the command runs so `z="{}"` is a literal assignment.

Probably the most straightforward approach here is to launch a shell with `-exec` where you can pass the filename as an argument and perform manipulations on it.

```
# launch one shell per file found
find . -iname "a*" -exec /bin/bash -c 'mv "${1}" "${1/x/y}"' _ {} \;
# launch one shell to handle all files in a single command - faster if you have a lot of files
find . -iname "a*" -exec /bin/bash -c 'for file ; do mv "${file}" "${file/x/y}" ; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: very nice, would you please explain the `+` character role at the end of the second command line? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See `-exec command {} +` in the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). Instead of running a new instance of `command` for each file found, it passes ALL the found files to a single instance of `command` (or as few instances as possible, if it can't pass them all in a single argument list). This typically improves performance, especially if you are matching a lot of files, but does require `command` to be able to handle more than one file (which is why the shell script in my example uses a for-loop instead of just calling mv).

Comment: Thanks. The "bash -c" solution is what I'm currently using but I was wondering if that can be avoided, namely, using "mv" w/o running a new shell instance.

Comment: `mv` specifically, no. It can't perform pattern-based renaming on files, so you have to let another tool do the manipulation of the filename. There are tools like `rename` that can do pattern-based renaming on files that you could use instead if you don't want to pass off to a shell.

Comment: An example using the [util-linux rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) might look like: `find . -iname "a*" -exec rename x y {} \;` or `find . -iname "a*" -exec rename x y {} +`